# Map an array of values to an array of each value's rank in the array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a array like this:

```
$row_arr_1=array(7,9,5,10);
```

now I want to get the result array like this:

```
$row_arr_2=array(3,2,4,1);
```

Explanation:

As `10` is the largest value in `row_arr_1`, then it will be replaced with value 1.

Similarly, as `9` is the 2nd highest value of `row_arr_1`, then it will be replaced by 2 and so on.

I tried to sort the values of `row_arr_1`  but the position is changed.

How 
can i get my desired result?

Comment: show code what u have tried so far?

Comment: So the actual question is _"I want to map an array of values to an array of each value's rank in the array"_

Comment: In your case, using `arsort()` will solve this problem.

Comment: @Phil, Exactly.My question is for php....not for jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using [rsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) and [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
$row_arr_1=array(7,9,5,10);
$row_copy = $row_arr_1;
$row_arr_2 = array();
rsort($row_copy);
foreach($row_arr_1 as $val) {
    $row_arr_2[] = array_search($val, $row_copy) + 1;
}
print_r($row_arr_2);
```

https://eval.in/990078

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`arsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) to sort the array while preserving keys, and use those keys for your array via [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$row_arr_1 = array(7,9,5,10);
$row_arr_1_backup = $row_arr_1;


arsort($row_arr_1_backup);
$row_arr_2 = array_keys($row_arr_1_backup);

asort($row_arr_2);
$row_arr_2 = array_keys($row_arr_2);


array_walk($row_arr_2, function(&$item, &$key) {
    $item = $item + 1;
});
```

You have to duplicate the original array, since arsort will sort the actual array it points to, rather than returning a new array.

Comment: Is it wrong because it is off by one? eg `Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 2
)` instead of `Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 3
)`? I noticed that, and it can be fixed with `array_walk`. But it is still the correct array in the sense of the new array is a ranking of the source array.

Comment: You have to sort the keys again to get the desired output (still off by one, but still can be fixed with array_walk if needed). Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row_arr_1_old = array(7, 9, 5, 10);
$row_arr_1 = array(7, 9, 5, 10);
rsort($row_arr_1);

$test = [];
foreach ($row_arr_1_old as $key => $value) {
    $test[] = array_search($value, $row_arr_1);
}

print_r($test);
```

Comment: Never post code-only answers on StackOverflow.  Unexplained answers are low value on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and thousands of future researchers.  If you are going to dedicate your time to supporting this community, always post complete answers.

Answer (score 0):

For best efficiency try to reduce total function calls; this especially means minimizing / eliminating iterated function calls.

This is my slightly more efficient version of ahsan's answer.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LphJk))

```
$copy = $arr = [7, 9, 5, 10];
rsort($arr);                      // generates: [10, 9, 7, 5]
$flipped = array_flip($arr);      // generates: [10 => 0, 9 => 1, 7 => 2, 5 => 3]
foreach($copy as $v) {
    $result[] = ++$flipped[$v];   // adds one to each accessed value from $flipped
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 3,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 4,
  3 => 1,
)
```